# MomentJS - inconsistent comparisons?

Tags: momentjs

Been trying to understand what's causing this weird issue. Can anyone see why the below logs out the first two lines as below rather than all true?

```
checking dates:  true true
checking dates2:  false true
2021-03-23T00:00:00 2021-03-23T00:00:00
true
```

```
const moment = require("moment");

const day = moment().subtract(1, "years");

console.log("day: ", day.format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00"), day.subtract(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00"));

let startDate = "2021-03-23";
let startDate2 = "2021-03-23T00:00:00";

console.log(
  "checking dates: ",
  moment(startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00") > day.subtract(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00"),
  moment(startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00") < day.add(1, "years").format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00")
);

console.log(
  "checking dates2: ",
  moment(startDate2).format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00") > day.subtract(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00"),
  moment(startDate2).format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00") < day.add(1, "years").format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00")
);

console.log(moment(startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00"), moment(startDate2).format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00"));
console.log(moment(startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00") == moment(startDate2).format("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, day variable is being modified by momentjs so any operation on it changes day value itself rather than the new variable! Need to bear that in mind if using the same base var in multiple places - it's not fixed